# Recolour image based on lower resolution version

Tags: color, gimp

I want to recreate the following image at a much higher resolution, so it will be suitable for printing in large.

[image: Pictures of an ice cream cone overlaid with the text "I scream, you scream, we all scream for the times we life in are truly terrifying".]

I have found a place where I can purchase [a high-resolution version of the ice cream cone](http://stockfresh.com/image/678137/fruit-ice-cream-isolated-on-white-background), as well as (a good imitation of) [the font](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page). The only difficult (to me) part of putting the image together is recolouring the stock photo to match the ice cream in the smaller image as closely as possible. I somehow want to keep the small-scale detail of the higher resolution image while preserving the colour of the smaller image. I was hoping someone here could explain to me how to do this.

The only software I have on hand is Gimp, so I would prefer to do it there. If doing this is for some reason next to impossible in Gimp and very easy in (some recent-ish version of) Photoshop, I might be able to get access to a computer with Photoshop for a few hours, but that would be much less practical for me.

(ETA: To be clear, I have permission from the creator of the image to do this.)

Comment: Does a tutorial like [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Recolor-Anything-on-Gimp) help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this answer doesn't address your specific Gimp question, but it **does** provide a solution.

I find that font, along with its kerning and spacing, a bit atrocious.... But anyway.....

The easiest solution is to purchase the image as it is, not try to recolor the wrong image:

[image: ice cream]

<sub>Click the image to load it at www.dreamstime.com</sub>

People often take the shortest possible route to something. That font choice, to me, makes it clear the creator isn't really a designer... so a stock photo or photo of the actual ice cream cones *must* exist somewhere. It was merely a matter of the right search terms to find it. The image, as it is, is already available at [**www.dreamstime.com**](http://www.dreamstime.com) as well as other stock sites I'm sure.

Stock photo + uncredited quote from [W. Kamau Bell](http://www.wkamaubell.com/) (Kamau saying this quote is used in an advertisement on Comedy Central to promote the next episode of his television show)... do you *need* permission for that? The original creator was merely "borrowing" content to begin with. Guess that's a different matter altogether. :)

Comment: This is cheating! ;)

Comment: Cheating in a good way :)

Comment: Ah thank you! Indeed, not an answer to my question but definitely a solution to my problem. I had tried to find this image but apparently not quite hard enough; and I did not know that this joke is someone else's.

(Though: I do think the choice of font/color/spacing/drop shadow/stock photo (note how fake the cone looks) works really well with the quote, which is why I like the picture.)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still want to do it in **Gimp**, the easiest / fastest way would be something like this:

- Open your image;
- Using the `Lasso` or the `Free Select Tool`, select the area you want to re-color (the ice-cream itself);
- Add a new layer, and using the selection you have created before, fill it with the color you want to use;
- Go to the `Layers` tab, and in the dropdown select `Overlay`.

[image]

<sub>[Source](http://www.ahotw.com/2009/06/10/gimp-layers-mode-opacity/) of Image (also contains explanations about layer modes)</sub>

You can re-use this layer for all the colors you need, just duplicate the overlay color layer and paint with a new color.